# What does a specific function represent in the 2D space?

Tags: geometry, functions, control-theory, lyapunov-functions

Consider the following Lyapunov candidate function:

$$ V(x,y,q_i) = \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{2}y^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln\big(\cosh(q_{i})\big) \tag1$$

where $q_{i} = \sqrt{(x-x_{i})^2 + (y-y_{i})^2} - L, \ L>0 \ (\text{constant})$, $n\geq1$ is an arbitrary positive integer number. The symbols $x,y\in \mathbb{R} $ are scalars representing the position of a rigid body in 2D space. The positive integer $n$ corresponds to the number of other units in the 2D space, the position of which is known. So, the pairs $(x_i, y_i), i=1,\dots,n$ represent the positions of $n$ bodies in the 2D space. Consequently, the summation term denotes the potential energy of the system with $(x_i,y_i)$ being known.

I would like to understand what does the function $V(x,y,q_i)$ represent for different values of the arguments $x,y$ in the 2D space. If there wasn't the summation term, then it would certainly represent a circle in the 2D space. I am not sure about its representation in the above case where the summation term exists. Does it still represent a circle (or an ellipse) with different radius and center than the case without the summation term ?

What I am looking for, is to understand the type of the Lyapunov surfaces (level surfaces) defined by equation (1). It should be noted that (1) possesses the characteristics of Lyapunov functions:

1. $V(x,y,q_i) = 0$ if and only if $(x,y,q_i) = 0$.
2. $V(\cdot)$ is a positive continuously differentiable function satisfying $V(x,y,q_i) > 0 \ \forall (x,y,q_i)\neq (0,0,0)$.

Comment: why not goto an online plotter and plot some of the surfaces and see what it looks like? [eg](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot3D%5B%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%2F2%2BLog%5BCosh%5BSqrt%5Bx%5E2%2By%5E2%5D-2%5D%5D%2BLog%5BCosh%5BSqrt%5B%28x-1%29%5E2%2By%5E2%5D-1%5D%5D%2C%7Bx%2C-2%2C2%7D%2C%7By%2C-2%2C2%7D%5D)

Comment: Did that in desmos but I'm not sure if I can extract a certain conclusion. I would like something in a more formal way, let's say.

Comment: The equations are unclear... $x$ seems to be a vector of dimension $n$, ok (here 2d, so $n=2$). What do you mean with $x^2$ then? Is it $x^Tx$? If so you should write it like that. And what is $x-x_i$? Vector minus scalar, element-wise? And how does the summation produce a scalar value in the end if its a vector? Please fix the math.

Comment: Added some explanation in terms of the symbols.